# How can I get the Global Resource Object outside of the context of a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, httpmodule

I am trying to replace some text in the response with a value from the Global Resources file using a HttpModule.

I can replace the text fine but I can't get hold of the Global Resource object.

I tried outputting ASP.NET code e.g.

```
<%= GetGlobalResourceObject(\"Labels\", \"ReplacementText\"); %>
```

But obviously this doesn't work because my HTTP Module runs after ASP.NET code has been executed.

Is there a way to get the value of a resource progamatically in a HttpModule? I have a HttpApplication object to work with.

Would a valid approach be to place the value in the HttpContext.Items collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked around this by inserting the resource into the HttpContext.Current.Items collection during Page_Load of the control where I want the module to run. Then accessing that from the HttpModule.